# AWS Device Farm - Android 13 contacts system app not available

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, aws-device-farm, python-appium

I am trying to add a contact in an Android 13 device for a test case of getting device contacts from our app, but it seems the system app com.google.android.contacts is not actually installed in the device. Tried to install it in pre-test phase through spec yml file with the following command (which actually returns a successful installation):

[image]

But when trying to start the Contacts app through an Appium Python test package it seems Appium not being able to find any Contacts app activity:

[image]

I tried with several Android 13 public devices (Samsung, Pixel, etc) but it throws the same results.

How can I make Contacts app activity visible for Appium?